# php-fpm as service on Centos 7

Tags: php, centos7, systemd, php-7

php 7 built from sources

While trying

```
systemctl enable php-fpm.service
```

get

```
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

While trying

```
chkconfig --levels 235 php-fpm on
```

get the same log :)

Update:

Somehow I managed to start by `chkconfig`, but i dont remember how. After reinstall OS and using `PHP 7.0.6-dev`.

Comment: Any updates about your question? Still need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, as for php 7.3, I use such approach after build php:

```
1. cp /path-to-php-src/sapi/fpm/php-fpm.service /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service
2. systemctl enable php-fpm.service
```

Content of file is similar to answer of Renato Mefi

Answer (score 3):

Since you are compiling your own PHP the unit/service need to be created, you can do it via chkconfig as you did or you can try to follow some guidelines, which I would recomend:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html

Example file from the first tutorial:

```
[Unit]
Description=The PHP 7 FastCGI Process Manager
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/opt/php-7.0.3/var/run/php-fpm.pid
ExecStart=/opt/php-7.0.3/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /opt/php-7.0.3/etc/php-fpm.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I saw the updated you already solved the issue, but I'll leave it here since it can help more people!